# Shell Script: How do I turn "virsh list | grep MediaWiki" into an if condition?

Tags: scripting, shell, grep

I'm trying to determine if a given Virtual Machine is running using a shell script.

The command "virsh list | grep MediaWiki", when run manually, returns one line if the Virtual Machine is running, and returns nothing when it's not.

I'm trying to use:

```
if [`virsh list | grep MediaWiki` !== ""]
then
        echo "The MediaWiki VM is Running!"
else
        echo "Not Running!"
fi
```

But I don't think I've got the syntax quite right. With the above code, it claims the machine is running whether it is or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an exclamation mark followed by two equal signs for "not equal". It should be "!=". Also there needs to be a space after the left square bracket and one before the right square bracket. Also, to test against a null string like that, you have to use double square brackets. The preferred way to do command substitution is with `$()` instead of backticks.

```
if [[ $(virsh list | grep MediaWiki) != "" ]]
```

This all presumes that you're using a shell like Bash that supports these features. If not then this should work:

```
if [ `virsh list | grep MediaWiki` ]
```

Comment: didn't even see that...good catch =)

Answer (score 2):

You can check return value of `grep -q` if you don't need grep results. It returns 0 if something matched.

```
if virsh list | grep -q MediaWiki
then
    echo "The MediaWiki VM is Running!"
else
    echo "Not Running!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing to keep in mind is that if your command returns null, or "", then you want to use the old DOS trick for comparing nulls:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo=`<command stuff here>`
if [ "X$foo" == "X" ] 
        then 
                echo "returned null"
        else
                echo "return positive"
fi
```

Check out the [scripting guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/testconstructs.html)

Comment: quite welcome....pointers to documentation are always free =)